# Indicative Python prints

Tags: python

I would like it if there was some way to generate a more indicative python prints: when printing some value, not only the result will be printed out,
but also the expression that got me that result.

For example, lets say I have:

```
>>> x = 1
```

Then, for printing x and its type, we get:

```
>>> print x ; print type(x)
1
<type 'int'>
```

I would like to get somthing like:

```
>>> print x ; print type(x)
x: 1
type(x): <type 'int'>
```

I've tried using locals(), inspect module, but I couldn't get this result.
Any id
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to overload the build in `print` functionality?

Comment: I don't think you can directly overload print as it is a statement and not a method (hence why it doesn't need brackets). You could overload write on sys.stdout though.

Comment: just in case: debugging is done with debuggers, not print.

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly write a function for this purpose:

```
def print_ex(expr, globals=None, locals=None):
    res = eval(expr, globals, locals)
    print expr + ":", res
    print "type(" + expr + "):", type(res)
```

Example:

```
>>> print_ex("2 + 3")
2 + 3: 5
type(2 + 3): <type 'int'>
```

Note that `eval()` executes arbitrary expressions, so make sure you never pass a string from an untrusted source to `print_ex()`.

If you don't like the need to explicitly pass `locals()` and `globals()`, you could also use

```
frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
globals = frame.f_globals
locals = frame.f_locals
```

to automatically use the `globals()` and `locals()` of the calling frame.

Comment: eval is not "inherently unsafe". eval is just a tool, and is only unsafe when used to run untrusted code. There are legitimate uses of eval which are completely safe.

Comment: I like this one too. Personally I'd add an optional argument with a namespace for `eval` like in my answer, so you can do `print_ex('a', locals())` to work with variable names.

Comment: @Bryan: Yes, thanks.  I was too lazy to explain what's exactly the problem with `eval()`, but I felt I need to warn about it somehow.  Well, on SO you never get away with this attitude... :)

Answer (score 1):

This demonstrates the most reasonable way I can think to easily show the information you want:

```
def info(name, namespace):
    thing = namespace[name]
    print "%s: %s" % (name, thing)
    print "type(%s): %s" % (name, type(thing))
```

To use it, give the name of the object you're interested in, and the namespace:

```
$ python -i info.py 
>>> a = 1
>>> info('a', locals())
a: 1
type(a): <type 'int'>
>>>
```

Of course, you could split this up into two different functions, subclass your favourite logging module and add it as a method, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own function:

```
def detailed_printer(expression):
    result = eval(expression)
    print(expression+": "+str(result))
    return result
```

(This way you can also get the result from the return value)

*python 3 syntax